# LISP, cond returning nil everytime

Tags: function, recursion, lisp, common-lisp, helper

Why does this always return nil when its obviously adding it to lst???

Please help!

Thank You!

```
CL-USER 1 : 1 > (defun constants-aux (form lst)
                  (cond ((null form) lst)
                        ((eq (car form) 'implies) (constants-aux (cdr form) lst))
                        ((eq (car form) 'not) (constants-aux (cdr form) lst))
                        ((eq (car form) 'and) (constants-aux (cdr form) lst))
                        ((eq (car form) 'or) (constants-aux (cdr form) lst))
                        ((atom (car form)) (print (car form)) (cons (car form) (list lst)) (delete-duplicates lst) (constants-aux (cdr form) lst))
                        (T (constants-aux (car form) lst) (constants-aux (cdr form) lst))))
CONSTANTS-AUX

CL-USER 2 : 1 > (defun constants (form)
                   (constants-aux form nil))
CONSTANTS

CL-USER 3 : 1 > constants '(IMPLIES (NOT Q) (IMPLIES Q P))

Q 
Q 
P 
NIL
```

Comment: You are working in the debugger. `cl-user 3 : 1 >` means that you are in debug level 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You doing it wrong in so many ways.

**1.** - Why create -aux function, when you can just use optional arguments?

```
(defun constants (form &optional lst)
  (cond
    ((null form) lst) ...
```

**2.** - You don't need so many similar branches, you can write:

```
((find (car form) '(implies not and or))
 (constants (cdr form) lst))
```

**3.** - [delete-duplicates](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_dup.htm) MAY modify your list, but don't think it have to, and even if it will, the modification it makes not what you wanted. You should use result of it. I think you got even a STYLE-WARNING, in SBCL it looks like this for your code:

```
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The return value of DELETE-DUPLICATES should not be discarded.
```

Read warnings, it helps.

I don't understand what result are you expecting, so I can't modify your function to work properly, but I'll try to show you where problem(s) is. Your code for last two cond branches:

```
((atom (car form))
         (print (car form))
         (cons (car form) (list lst)) ;; Result is ignored
         (delete-duplicates lst)      ;; Result is ignored
         (constants-aux (cdr form) lst))
```

You should write:

```
(constant-aux (cdr form) (delete-duplicates lst))

        (T
           (constants-aux (car form) lst) ;; Result is ignored
           (constants-aux (cdr form) lst))))
```

May be (depends on what you want to get) you should write:

```
(cons
   (constants-aux (car form) lst)
   (constants-aux (cdr form) lst))
```

**4** I'm not shure, but it looks like you using print for debug, just use [trace](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_tracec.htm) instead. For your code it'll give you pretty good information what is going on with your list during execution:

```
  0: (CONSTANTS-AUX (IMPLIES (NOT Q) (IMPLIES Q P)) NIL)
    1: (CONSTANTS-AUX ((NOT Q) (IMPLIES Q P)) NIL)
      2: (CONSTANTS-AUX (NOT Q) NIL)
        3: (CONSTANTS-AUX (Q) NIL)

Q           4: (CONSTANTS-AUX NIL NIL)
          4: CONSTANTS-AUX returned NIL
        3: CONSTANTS-AUX returned NIL
      2: CONSTANTS-AUX returned NIL
      2: (CONSTANTS-AUX ((IMPLIES Q P)) NIL)
        3: (CONSTANTS-AUX (IMPLIES Q P) NIL)
          4: (CONSTANTS-AUX (Q P) NIL)

Q             5: (CONSTANTS-AUX (P) NIL)

P               6: (CONSTANTS-AUX NIL NIL)
              6: CONSTANTS-AUX returned NIL
            5: CONSTANTS-AUX returned NIL
          4: CONSTANTS-AUX returned NIL
        3: CONSTANTS-AUX returned NIL
        3: (CONSTANTS-AUX NIL NIL)
        3: CONSTANTS-AUX returned NIL
      2: CONSTANTS-AUX returned NIL
    1: CONSTANTS-AUX returned NIL
  0: CONSTANTS-AUX returned NIL
```

**5.** It'll be really easyer to answer if you explain what transformation you expecting from this code.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, changed a few things and used append instead, works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing is to proper format your code. Example:

```
(defun constants-aux (form lst)
  (cond ((null form) lst)
        ((eq (car form) 'implies) (constants-aux (cdr form) lst))
        ((eq (car form) 'not)     (constants-aux (cdr form) lst))
        ((eq (car form) 'and)     (constants-aux (cdr form) lst))
        ((eq (car form) 'or)      (constants-aux (cdr form) lst))
        ((atom (car form))
         (print (car form))
         (cons (car form) (list lst))
         (delete-duplicates lst)
         (constants-aux (cdr form) lst))
        (T
         (constants-aux (car form) lst)
         (constants-aux (cdr form) lst))))
```

Then you can simplify your code:

```
(defun constants-aux (form list)
  (cond ((null form) list)
        ((member (car form) '(implies not and or))
         (constants-aux (cdr form) list))
        ((atom (car form))
         (constants-aux (cdr form)
                        (adjoin (car form) list)))
        (T
         (constants-aux (car form) list)
         (constants-aux (cdr form) list))))
```

Then we may get rid of `car` and `cdr`.

```
(defun constants-aux (form list)
  (if (consp form)
      (destructuring-bind (head . tail)
          form
        (cond ((member head '(implies not and or))
               (constants-aux tail list))
              ((atom head)
               (constants-aux tail (adjoin head list)))
              (T
               (constants-aux head list)
               (constants-aux tail list))))
    list))
```

Then you can work a bit on the logic and make sure results are not ignored, make sure the adjoin thing is correct, and so on...